Is optional if other properties are undefined
I have the following DTO
export class UpsertSubscription {
  @Expose()
  @ValidateIf((o) => !o.monthly && !o.yearly)
  @IsNumber({}, { message: 'tiers.priceMustBeANumber' })
  @Min(0, { message: 'tiers.priceMustBeAtLeastZero' })
  public daily?: number;

  @Expose()
  @ValidateIf((o) => !o.daily && !o.yearly)
  @IsNumber({}, { message: 'tiers.priceMustBeANumber' })
  @Min(0, { message: 'tiers.priceMustBeAtLeastZero' })
  public monthly?: number;

  @Expose()
  @ValidateIf((o) => !o.daily && !o.monthly)
  @IsNumber({}, { message: 'tiers.priceMustBeANumber' })
  @Min(0, { message: 'tiers.priceMustBeAtLeastZero' })
  public yearly?: number;
}

the ValidateIf decorator is supposed to make the property optional in case one of the other two is defined. However, if let's say daily is 10, which is valid, monthly can be set to any value, like "something different", which is not fine.
Is there a way to make the properties optional if one is defined?

Yes, there is. I see that you are checking in ValidateIf if other properties are truthy, that is something different than checking if the other property is defined. Keep that in mind

Thanks I missed that. but how do I make it optional if they are defined? so that if they provide the value it will be validated however if they don't it is fine since the other props are defined.
